# Como retornar um objeto a partir de uma referência dinâmica no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, objetos

Preciso criar um código JavaScript que retorna um objeto já criado com uma referência dinâmica pelo nome/id do mesmo.

Basicamente isso:

```
// Define class
function Test(num) {

    this.msg = "Message";   
    this.num = num;

}

// Create objects
var objTest_1 = new Test(1);
var objTest_2 = new Test(2);
var objTest_3 = new Test(3);


// Call objects in loop
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { 
/*
    // Static reference
    alert( objTest_1.msg + objTest_1.num );
    //or
    alert( Object(objTest_1).msg + Object(objTest_1).num );
*/

    // Dinamic reference
    alert( Object("objTest_" + i).msg + Object("objTest_" + i).num );  // Return error "NaN"
}
```

Ps: Neste exemplo eu apenas busco algumas "property" do objeto, mas no meu código real eu preciso realmente retornar um objeto já existente para chamar um método específico que o mesmo contém.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o objeto global para acessar variáveis **globais** dinamicamente. No browser o objeto global é o `window` (pode-se usar o `this` também, que referencia o mesmo objeto global que o `window` aponta).

```js
// Define class
function Test(num) {

    this.msg = "Message";   
    this.num = num;

}

// Create objects
var objTest_1 = new Test(1);
var objTest_2 = new Test(2);
var objTest_3 = new Test(3);


// Call objects in loop
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { 
    // Dinamic reference
    console.log( window["objTest_" + i].msg + window["objTest_" + i].num );
}
```

Se esses objetos são declarados com `var` dentro de funções as variáveis serão associadas ao que é chamado de *Activation Object*. Mas diferente do objeto global, não há uma maneira de acessá-lo, e consequentemente não há uma maneira de acessar as variáveis associadas a ele.

Nesse caso você tem a opção de guardar os objetos em um array, como sugerido em uma das respostas, ou usar a função `eval`. Supondo que seu código esteja dentro de uma função anônima:

```js
(function() {
  // Define class
  function Test(num) {

    this.msg = "Message";   
    this.num = num;

  }

  // Create objects
  var objTest_1 = new Test(1);
  var objTest_2 = new Test(2);
  var objTest_3 = new Test(3);


  // Call objects in loop
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { 
    // Dinamic reference
    console.log( eval("objTest_" + i).msg + eval("objTest_" + i).num );
  }
})()
```

`eval` vai executar a string que você passar como parâmetro. Mas cuidado! A função `eval` deve ser usada em último caso e com muita cautela. Usar `eval` é perigoso porque, dependendo de como você gerar a string a ser executada, pode acabar injetando algum script malicioso na máquina do usuário.

Referências:

- [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
- [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score 2):

O mais fácil é usar uma array:

```js
// Define class

function Test(num) {

    this.msg = "Message";   
    this.num = num;

}

var objetos = [];
objetos.push( new Test(1) );
objetos.push( new Test(2) );
objetos.push( new Test(3) );

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    // ^ IMPORTANTE, faltava o var

    alert( objetos[i].msg + objetos[i].num );
}
```

Comment: A grande questão é que quem gera os objetos é a framework do sistema que estou utilizando, basicamente eu não consigo alterar a forma que eles são construídos.

Comment: @lorduakiti esse framework cria os objetos com `var` mesmo?

Comment: @PanterA não saberia lhe informar com plena certeza mas acredito que sim!

Answer (score 0):

Descobri uma forma de chamar um objeto javascript pelo seu id de forma dinâmica:

```js
window["objTest_" + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o

> eval()

Na prática o **eval()** executa uma string como se fosse um código javascript.

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var a = eval("x * y") + "<br>";
var b = eval("2 + 2") + "<br>";
var c = eval("x + 17") + "<br>";

var res = a + b + c;
```

**Resultado**

```
200
4
27
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Exemplo usando em objetos.

```
var obj = { a: 20, b: 30 };
var propname = getPropName();  //returna "a" ou "b"

eval( "var result = obj." + propname );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval